# Textbox onchange event

Tags: c#, javascript

So I have a text box, where I add an onchange event of markAsException.

My javascript is -

```
function markAsException(recordID) {
    //alert("Exception");

    //mark exception column
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_lblScrollException_" + recordID).innerText = "Exception";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_lblScrollException_" + recordID).style.color = "#FF0000";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_tdScrollException_" + recordID).style.backgroundColor = "#99CCFF";

    //enable comments ddl and remove blank (first item)
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_ddlCommentId_" + recordID).disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_ddlCommentId_" + recordID).focus();
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_ddlCommentId_" + recordID).options[0] = null;
}
```

What I want to do is, when a user changes the value in a textbox, to mark a column as "Exception", and then focus a drop down list where they have to chose the reason for the exception.

This is what happens.. If I am on that text box and change it, then tab, it tabs to the drop down list.

However, if I change the value and then simply click in another text box on the form, I don't focus the drop down list.

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Not an answer because it's off topic but I don't believe you can assume .NET controls will always be generated with the same ClientID each time.  This article may help: http://encosia.com/robust-aspnet-control-referencing-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using JQuery's [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function.

The advantage is that it will be more stable across different browsers.

Something like:

```
    $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').change(function(){
      // extract the recordID from the textbox - perhaps with an attribute?
      markAsException(recordID);
    });
```

My comment was getting longer so I'm expanding:

Take a look at the JQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for setting this up as the page finishes loading.  If tb is the ID of your textbox your selector would be

```
$('#<%= tb.ClientID %>')
```

I would suggest you replace your code and use

```
tb.Attributes.Add("recordID", recordId.ToString());
```

This will add the ID you need onto the textbox tag.  Once you're in the function I outlined above you can use the following selector to get the recordID in javascript

```
var recordID = $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').attr('recordID');
```

All together

```
  $(document.ready(function(){
    $('#<%= tb.ClientID %>').change(function(){
      var recordID = $('#<%= tb.ClientID %>').attr('recordID');
      if(recordID){
        markAsException(recordID);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: My c# code is - tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "markAsException('" + recordId + "')");.. how would I change that? (Where tb is the TextBox control)